# One word for 'automatic nature' of doing certain things?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a chess player. Quite often, when I am in a familiar position, I automatically reach out to move a certain piece to a certain square without thinking too much. That's usually the first move that I see and I make it rather "automatically" in a blitz game. But sometimes this automatic way of moving pieces causes me to make mistakes. I need to break this "automaticity", if that is even the right word? Looking up the Oxford Reference-

> The ability to perform a task by automatic processing, independent of
>   conscious control and attention. Strong automaticity is almost
>   entirely automatic and can be carried out without attention. Partial
>   automaticity refers to processing that can be performed without
>   conscious control, but which is performed better with attention.

However, this isn't exactly the sense in which I want to use a word to describe the automatic way I do things. In my case, sometimes the "automaticity" can be a bad and undesired thing and not an "ability". So is there a word for this?

Comment: Interestingly, [*automaticity*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automaticity#other-words) actually is a word.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I disagree about this being a duplicate. This question asks about the case where the automatic move is a bad one, not a correct one.

Comment: @ThePhoton Whether it's good or bad is irrelevant. It's still the [automatic thing] that needs to be broken. Even if you want to call it a ***bad*** *habit*, it's still a *habit*. If the question really is looking for a word that means something bad and never good (like **vice**), then the question needs to be edited to make that clear. But with the way the question is written that's not the case.

Comment: Hitting the brake when a child is about to run in front of the car becomes “automatic” and occurs too quickly to result from a conscious thought process.  So too the actions of an experienced soccer player, for example. Sometimes we can ask ourselves to think it through first (e.g., in chess).

Comment: Maybe the angle is off a bit. Perhaps it's a matter of separating confidence from arrogance (called over-confidence)/aggressiveness. Confidence always leaves room for learning; doesn't assume superiority.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation, we often say we're doing something by **muscle memory**, even if the action isn't a physical one. However this usually has a positive implication, meaning you're so well practiced that you make the correct move without thinking.

You could also say you're doing something **by rote**, although implies a highly repetitive action.

And, of course, in chess when there are such automatic moves during the opening phase of the game, they are called **book moves**.

For the case where the move is bad, you might call it **impulsive** or **unthinking**.